# Enable Require Customer's Billing Address in Paypal

Tags: magento2, admin, paypal-express

I need paypal express to provide me address information and I am trying to enable this option in magento paypal express module.
Require Customer's Billing Address - Yes
There is a little note under the select field:

> This feature needs be enabled first for the merchant account through
>   PayPal technical support.

I try to find that option in my sandbox account, but I am not able to find it.

In that post https://community.magento.com/t5/Payments-PayPal/Shipping-address-is-set-to-the-customer-s-Paypal-shipping/td-p/45557
I found that it is possible to be done in sandbox by myself and techincal support is reuired only for production environment.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with that issue?

Comment: You have set enable Require Customer's Billing Address  option from configuration from backend?

Comment: Yes, the option is enable in the Magento admin panel, but when I try to checkout I get: PayPal gateway has rejected request. Billing address request is not enabled for merchant (#11601: Request for billing address failed).

Comment: It is not duplicate, I want exactly opposite this option to be enable, but I am not able to find it where to enable it in the Payapl Sandbox account.